# Using Arduino to learn AVR programming

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, programmer, atmel-studio

I want to learn AVR C programming instead of arduino programming. I have an arduino UNO board and few Atmega328 chips that I bought, and Atmel studio for programming. Can I use Arduino Uno board as programmer to flash the chips from Atmel Studio? Or any other alternatives?

Comment: Without a lot of knowledge on this subject, [this post on the Arduino Forums](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,176375.0.html) and it looks related. For reference, what you want to do is use the Uno as an ISP.

Comment: Do your self a favor and buy a real programmer like the Atmel ICE, Dragon etc... You will thank me.

Answer (score 1):

If your chips have a bootloader already installed in them, you can use any USB -> Serial cable (FTDI cable) to program them in-circuit on their Rx/Tx pins. If not, you can use the Uno to program a boot loader into them (one time) and program them with the cable from then on.

To use standard C, you can use the bare chips or the UNO. You'll want a different environment than the Arduino IDE, though. That can be anything from an editor, the the gnu compiler tools run from a command line, to almost any other IDE. A number of people, myself included, use the Eclipse IDE with an AVR plug-in and do almost everything from writing the code to programming the AVR from within it. (I say 'almost' only because I personally prefer a full-blown programming editor, run outside of the IDE, for initial creation of sizeable projects or major edits and rewrites. That isn't necessary, though).

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting out then Atmel Studio is a good option - it's very easy to install and get up and running, and I use it.

To use an Arduino as an ISP you're going to need to use AVRDude.  You can configure Atmel Studio to flash chips using AVRDude - I struggled with this but eventually got it working, you can look [here](http://www.crash-bang.com/using-usbtiny-with-atmelstudio/) if it will help - not specifically for the Arduino as ISP, but should get you started.

Finally you should also double-check whether you have ATmega328-PU or ATmega328P-PU - AVRDude doesn't support the ATmega328-PU (without the P) so you'll need to do a workaround (again something that I've been caught out with in the past, [here's how I worked around it] (http://www.crash-bang.com/resource/bootload-atmega328/)

Good luck - programming the AVR directly is more challenging but gives you more control.

Comment: AVRDude does support the ATmega328 (no P) - however, the configuration file shipped when it is distributed by the Arduino folks may not include an entry for it.

Comment: Essentially, it is to use menu *Tools* -> *External Tools* to define a new menu command that calls AVRDUDE with the appropriate parameters, using `$(TargetDir)` and `$(TargetName)` to construct the full path to the hex file created by Atmel Studio.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to learn AVR C programming instead of arduino programming.

It's not really clear what you think the difference is. You can use the Arduino IDE to do "straight AVR" programming, for example:

```
int main ()
  {
  DDRB = bit (5);  // pin 13
  DDRB |= bit (4);  // pin 12

  while (true)
    {
    PINB = bit (5); // pin 13
    PINB = bit (4); // pin 12
    }
  }
```

The AVR register names (eg. DDRB, PINB, PORTB and so on) will be included by the IDE, however you don't have to use a single Arduino library or function if you don't want to.

Comment: Ah, cool you can actually "override" the main function and not use the setup & loop functions?
But to be honest I would let everyone drop the arduino IDE. I think code-completion and/or code hints are very usefull for beginners.

Comment: Certainly, and you can specify an editor of your choice for the IDE. I just don't think that "Arduino programming", "C Programming" and the supplied IDE are different things. The IDE basically implements C++ so there is really no "Arduino language".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Atmel Studio + Visual Micro plugin to easily get started with atmega328 + support for the uno board (easily program, use arduino libraries etc). Checkout here.  http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-for-Atmel-Studio.aspx

Comment: Just found in this forum that a similar answer exists for a similar question. http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/what-changes-i-have-to-take-care-while-coding-from-atmel-studio-instead-of-ardui